# Get ctx based on list GUID

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, ecb-menu

I want to get list `ctx` based on GUID.

My requirement is to develop a context menu security webpart.

I want to display the list/library context menu items in my application page which is user selected list/library.

So that they can select the context menu item to hide/disable.

I think in `Core.js`

```
function BuildMenuWithInit(ctx)

function BuildMenu(ctx)
```

above functions is generating the context menu items.

Both functions are taking list/library `ctx`.

So I want to get the `ctx` based on list/library GUID.

Can any one provide the solution for this problem, like

```
function getContextInfo(ListId) {    
    // some logic   
    return ctxT;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint JavaScript Library contains the `SP.Ribbon.NativeUtility.getCtxForView` method that could be used for retrieving `Context Info` by `View id`, for example:

```
//Retrieve Context Info by View Id
var viewId = '{C441B540-C04D-4592-A526-26F57DA6914A}';
var ctxForView = SP.Ribbon.NativeUtility.getCtxForView(viewId);
console.log(currentCtx);
```

In order to retrieve `Context Info` by `List id` the following function could be used:

```
//Retrieve Context Info by List Id
function findCtxForList(listId)
{ 
   var ctx = null;
   for(var viewId in g_ViewIdToViewCounterMap) {
       var curCtxNo = g_ViewIdToViewCounterMap[viewId];
       var curCtx = g_ctxDict['ctx' + curCtxNo];
       if(curCtx.listName === listId.toUpperCase()) {
           ctx = currentCtx;         
           break;
       }
   }
   return ctx;
}
```

Usage

```
var listId = '{C627B132-B9B7-424D-ACA8-C961EB9213C5}';
var ctxForList = findCtxForList(listId);
console.log(ctxForList);
```

Comment: your script is not working, i found some jquery script but it works only it the same list or library page. like http://sp2010/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx but i want to get ctx in custom application page. please refer below link for script https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/jquery-for-everyone-create-a-client-side-object-model.aspx

Comment: what exactly "is not working" ?

Comment: i tried to run the script but 'var viewId in g_ViewIdToViewCounterMap' and ' var ctxForView = SP.Ribbon.NativeUtility.getCtxForView(viewId);' is returning undefined, its not returning the ctx. note : i need to get the ctx in application page not in the same list or library page. so then only i can display the menu options to the client in my context security webpart.